# Unable to delete files using python file on windows even after giving full-control

Tags: python, python-3.x, iis, window

I recovered from a fully functioning server(Windows Server R2-2012) from my backup, and instead of overwriting the existing files, it created copies of all the files in my server.

I wrote a python(3.5.2) script to delete the files that has the name "2017-09-09 00-00 Copy of_Filename" but it still doesn't delete **few files**.
My folders and sub-directories have "full control" for the account I signed in with. I am manually able to delete the files, but my script or batch file couldn't. The error I'm getting is "permission denied"
I have run my batch file in administrative mode as well, but still no effect.

Python(3.5.2) script:

```
import os
import re
import fnmatch

f = open("log.txt","w+")
count = 1
for root, dirs, files in os.walk("c:\\Website\\",topdown=False):
   for fl in files:
    if re.match('2017-09-09 00-00 Copy of',fl ):
        try:
            file_path = os.path.join(root, fl)
            os.remove(file_path)
            print("Deleting file " + file_path)
        except:
            file_path = os.path.join(root, fl)
            f.write(str(count) + " " + file_path + "\n")
            #print(str(count) + " " + file_path + "\n")
            count+=1
f.close()
```

This is an example of the folder contents that I am trying to delete [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/suY1e.png). 
This is the access status of the folder. I am "Administrator"
[2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uaqPT.png)

I feel my server(IIS) is not running due to this error.
Any help is appreciated.

Comment: You mention **batch-file**, in your question and as a tag but I do not see any `batch-file` code. Do you have a specific question regarding `batch-files`?

Comment: It will be difficult to resolve the problem without logging the error code when `os.remove` fails. Is it access denied (5), sharing violation (32), file not found (2), path not found (3), or something else? Use `except OSError as e` instead of just `except`, and log `e.winerror` in addition to the file path that fails.

Comment: The error I'm getting is "Permission Denied".

Comment: Check the access control entries of one of the problem files via `icacls filename`. There could be an ACE that denies access to your account. Otherwise the files may be in a deleted state already, but something has them open, which prevents the filesystem from unlinking them. Use Sysinternals handle.exe or Process Explorer to look for open handles.