# Directory denied when it shouldn't be

Tags: python

I'm trying to delete all .rar files in a directory that I know I can access, write, read, etc (Even I'm the only user in this pc and hence the only admin that there is). When using the method `os.unlink`, it returns:

`PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: 'D:\\mc\\P\\Tomo5'`

This is the code I wrote:

```
import os
import glob

for numero_tomofor in range(5,100):
    tomopath = "Tomo" + str(numero_tomofor)
    path = "D:\\mc\P\\" + tomopath
    os.chdir(path)
    files= glob.glob("*.rar")
    for rar in files:
        os.unlink(rar)
```

The traceback is:

```
  File "C:/Users/sdf/PycharmProjects/Tkinter/OnlyPython/Namechanger2.py", line 11, in <module>
    os.unlink(rar)
PermissionError: [WinError 5] Acceso denegado: '033.rar'
```

Comment: Why are you calling `open()` on a directory?  I suspect that's where the error is actually occurring - but I can't tell for sure, since you didn't post the complete error traceback.

Comment: possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47128128/unable-to-delete-files-using-python-file-on-windows-even-after-giving-full-contr

try it, exact same way you are trying it..

Comment: the open() line was just messing around with things I read on the internet to see if it worked. the error traceback without the open() line is: File "C:/Users/sdf/PycharmProjects/Tkinter/OnlyPython/Namechanger2.py", line 11, in <module>
    os.unlink(rar)
PermissionError: [WinError 5] Acceso denegado: '033.rar'

Comment: Occurs with all the files, It starts by 33 because I moved other single handedly trying things to fix this